# Systems of multivariate polynomials with less affine roots than roots at infinity.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, nonlinear-system, projective-space

We are considering systems
of $n$ multivariate polynomials in $n$ variables with coefficients from $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$):

$p_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0,~~\ldots~~,p_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$.

We are interested in the common roots of such systems and assume a zero-dimensional solution set (only isolated roots).
Let $d_i$ be the degree of $p_i$ (largest degree of monomials with nonzero coefficient). Then by Bezout's theorem there are $m:=\prod_{i=1}^nd_i$ solutions in the projective space $\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\backslash\lbrace 0\rbrace$, counted with multiplicities.

These solutions split up into $m_a$ affine roots (points in $\mathbb{C}^n$) and $m_p$ projective solutions, which are the solutions of the homogenized system $p_i^h(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$ with $x_0$-component equal zero. Let's call those $m_p$ roots the *roots at infinity* (since they cannot be scaled back to affine space).

**Now the question** (sorry if the explanation was too extensive):
Can we find/construct systems of the above class that have strictly less affine roots than roots at infinity, $1<m_a<m_p$, and all roots are simple?
(of course, at least one $p_i$ should have degree$>1$).

We could show that this is **not possible** for simple cases (e.g., $n=2$, $d_1=d_2=2$) and suspect that this is not possible in general. We are no algebraic geometers and lack the tools to investigate this issue rigorously, so any help / tipps would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means for a root at infinity to be simple.

Comment: To our understanding, it's similar as for affine roots. I.e., for a root at infinity $p_i^h(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$ and no further differential functionals of $p_i$ vanish at the root.

Comment: OK. So, what happens with the system $p_1(x_1,x_2)=x_1$, $p_2(x_1,x_2)=x_2$? Only one zero, that zero is at infinity, and it's simple.

Comment: The zero is at $(0,0)$ and affine.

Comment: I thought the roots of the highest degree part were the roots at infinity.

Comment: Maybe that sentence was misleading (erased it). Roots at infinity occur when one makes the polynomials of the system homogeneous (all monomials have same degree) by introducing a new variable $x_0$ and multiplying powers of $x_0$ to every monomials: e.g., $x_1^2+x_2+1=0$ becomes $x_1^2+x_0x_2+x_0^2=0$. This does not change the "affine solutions", given by $(1,x_1,x_2)$ but introduces "roots at infinity" $(x_0=0,x_1,x_2)$ where the homogenous system vanishes. So the roots of infinity are an artifact of the homogenization.(your example was already homogeneous, no homogenization needed).

Comment: This sounds related to the Jacobian Conjecture where the problem is precisely showing all the roots are infinity except one. You can probably play with polynomial triangular examples to get an idea,

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for.

So, let $\deg p_i=d_i$ and we may assume $d_1\geq d_2\geq \cdots\geq d_n$. I will assume  that $d_n\geq 2$, linear equations create issues and am not sure how they can be handled.

We are assuming the homogenization of these have transversal intersections and thus there are $M=\prod d_i$ points in the intersection.

If $l_i$ are the leading forms of the $p_i$, then the points at infinity are the intersection of these $l_i$s. There are $n$ equations in $n-1$ projective space with finite intersection, so after suitable linear change (adding multiples of the last equation to the previous ones) we may assume $l_i , i<n$ intersect in finitely many points and $m_p$ is less than or equal to this number, since it is got by further intersecting with $l_n$. So, by Bezout, we get $m_p\leq \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} d_i=m$, while the total number of points are $M$. Thus, $m_a=M-m_p\geq m(d_n-1)\geq m\geq m_p$.

Here, I write down a linear case which is contrary to the above statements. Take $n=2, p_1=x_1, p_2=x_1+1$. Then $m_p=1, m_a=0$.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds already much more reasonable than what I would've be able to come up with.  Some questions, though: 1. what exactly do you mean by transversal intersections? 2. Why exactly do we need the 'suitable linear change'?